# Jquery form.serialize() do not manage checkboxes properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms, checkbox

I have a problem on an ajax form submission with Jquery.

Ajax call is working fine but my server receives only the last checked checkbox in the request data. This happens because `formdata` generated by the `serialize` function (and passed to my request headers) is formatted as follow

```
configuration[accessoires]:2
configuration[accessoires]:3
```

instead of

```
configuration[accessoires][0]:2
configuration[accessoires][1]:3
```

This is my code :

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('body').on('submit', 'form[name="configuration"]', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $form = $('form[name="configuration"]');
    var formData = $form.serialize(); // same result with $(this).serialize() or serializeArray()
    $.ajax({
        url : $form.attr('action'),
        type: $form.attr('method'),
        data : formData,
        success: function(html) {
          // success code
        }
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="configuration" action="blabla" method="POST">
  <input id="accessoire1" name="configuration[accessoires]" value="1" type="checkbox">
  <label for="accessoire1">blabla 1</label>
  
  <input id="accessoire2" name="configuration[accessoires]" value="2" type="checkbox">
  <label for="accessoire2">blabla 2</label>
  
  <input id="accessoire3" name="configuration[accessoires]" value="3" type="checkbox">
  <label for="accessoire3">blabla 3</label>
  
  <button id="app_submit">
    <span>submit</span>
  </button>
</form>
```

I am probably missing something but it looks like jquery doesn't detect my inputs are checkboxes with the same name.

Comment: You should use configuration[accessoires][0],configuration[accessoires][1] like that,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding same names for all the checkboxes, form doesnt take as an array you must specify it in the name itself see the snippet

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('body').on('submit', 'form[name="configuration"]', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $form = $('form[name="configuration"]');
    var formData = $(this).serialize();
    console.log(formData);
    $.ajax({
        url : $form.attr('action'),
        type: $form.attr('method'),
        data : formData,
        success: function(html) {
          // success code
        }
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="configuration" action="blabla" method="POST">
  <input id="accessoire1" name="configuration[accessoires][0]" value="1" type="checkbox">
  <label for="accessoire1">blabla 1</label>
  
  <input id="accessoire2" name="configuration[accessoires][1]" value="2" type="checkbox">
  <label for="accessoire2">blabla 2</label>
  
  <input id="accessoire3" name="configuration[accessoires][2]" value="3" type="checkbox">
  <label for="accessoire3">blabla 3</label>
  
  <button id="app_submit">
    <span>submit</span>
  </button>
</form>
```

Comment: I thought serializer was able to to it by itself. But by re-reading the [doc](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/) I see the point.. the generated query string takes the same index for all checked input with the same name. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

You could use .serializeArray() function. It will create javascript array of objects.

Comment: I precised in my snippet that's the same. ;)